# Sort the array of objects in react on the basis of time and created date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the `react js and redux.` Here ,
What I have is ,
an array of object which is like ,

```
quizList = [ { createdDate : 1543314832505, id:5bfd1d90d4ed830001f589fc, name:'abc'}, { createdDate : 1543314152180, id:5bfd1ae8d4ed830001f589f8, name:'pqr'}, { createdDate : 1543308600920, id:5bfd1d90d4ed830001f589ssq, name:'qqq'} ]
```

Now, what I am doing is ,

```
<div className="col p-0">
   <div id="accordion">
      {
      props.quizList.map((data, index) => ( 
      <QuizInCollapse index={index + 1} data={data}/>
      ))
      }
      {/* first collapse end */}
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, here I'm passing one by one object using is, map. Now, Here, What I tried to do is ,

I want to show this list as per the createdDate and time, so that latest will come at top .

so, here `createdDate` is the key that means it has the timestamp.

so I have taken the  date from it, like

```
    let currentDate = new Date(props.quizList.createdDate);
    let createdDate =  currentDate.toDateString();
    let createdTime = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString();
```

But after this? I am now anyone How can I sort this ?

SO, can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort array before mapping and here's how you do it. You don't need to convert it to Date object because sorting epoch milliseconds is simple and fast math.

If you want to reverse order, use `smallestToBiggest` instead.

```js
var quizList = [ 
  {createdDate : 1543314832505, id: '5bfd1d90d4ed830001f589fc', name:'abc'}, 
  {createdDate : 1543314152180, id: '5bfd1ae8d4ed830001f589f8', name:'pqr'}, 
  {createdDate : 1543308600920, id: '5bfd1d90d4ed830001f589ssq', name:'qqq'}
];

function smallestToBiggest(a, b) {
  return a.createdDate - b.createdDate;
}

function biggestToSmallest(a, b) {
  return b.createdDate - a.createdDate;
}

quizList.sort(biggestToSmallest);

// now you can map quizList
// it's already sorted
console.log(quizList);
```

Reference: [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

---

#### Edit

You use it like this:

```js
render() {
  const sortedList = props.quizList.sort((a, b) => b.createdDate - a.createdDate);

  return (
    <div className="col p-0">
      <div id="accordion">
        {sortedList.map((data, index) => (
          <QuizInCollapse
            index={index + 1}
            data={data}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Much simpler to do `return a.createdDate - b.createdDate;` for numeric sort

Comment: @charlietfl Haven't had a chance to use it myself at all, edited. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: data={this.props.quizList.sort(function(a,b){return b.createdDate - a.createdDate;})}   done it like this. I mean while sending props there itself I am checking so will it be okay ?

Comment: Rule is to return negative , positive or zero so subtraction accomplishes that

Comment: I have used your logic only, but just that I have used it in the props itself,

Answer (score 0):

Just like Array.map(), you can use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Array.sort() takes a callback function (just like .map) with 2 arguments (a and b), which you can use to compare. The compare function's return value can be:

- -1, a is less than b
- 0, a = b
- 1, a is greater than b

Here's an example.

```
function compareDatesInObjects(a, b) {
    const aCreatedDate = new Date(a.createdDate);
    const bCreatedDate = new Date(b.createdDate);
    if (aCreatedDate < bCreatedDate)
        return -1;
    if (aCreatedDate > bCreatedDate)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

const sorted = quizList.sort(compareDatesInObjects);
// and because sort() returns an array, you can even chain the Array functions.
const mappedAndSorted = quizList.sort(compareDatesInObjects).map(/* ... */);
```

Comment: `new Date` is redundant and not needed. That date gets cast back to number to do the comparisons

Comment: @charlietfl   used it like   data={this.props.quizList.sort(function(a,b){return b.createdDate - a.createdDate;})} done it like this. I mean while sending props there itself I am checking so will it be okay ?

Comment: @ganesh that object syntax is incorrect. See how Solo did it in edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.sort` method to sort the array and render the sorted array using `map`. Sorting operation should not be done in `render()` method, it should be done either in `componentDidMount` or `getDerivedStateFromProps`, the sorted array should be stored in component's state and you should use the state variable to render the array in `render()` method.

Comment: data={this.props.quizList.sort(function(a,b){return b.createdDate - a.createdDate;})} done it like this. I mean while sending props there itself I am checking so will it be okay ?

Comment: where are you passing the `data` ? can you share the updated code?